# Save Image and Display on Email

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this piece of code and it does the following:

Generate a barcode:

```
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qrCode = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(code, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
```

And then I save it as a png:

```
string publicPath = @"c:\inetpub\folder\Images\QRCodes\" + saveFile;

using (Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(publicPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        ms.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
        ms.Close();
    }
}
```

So far all this is working and working well.

Now I am trying to take this saved image and display it in an email, not as an attachment, but display the email and send it off, I have tried the following:

```
var message = "<img src='" + publicPath + "' width='500' />";

using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("xxx.xxx.x.xx"))
{
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress("example@domain.com");
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("webmaster@domain.com");
    MailMessage email = new MailMessage(from, to);
    email.Subject = "Subject Line";
    email.Body = message;
    email.IsBodyHtml = true;
    try
    {
        client.Send(email);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

This sends the email with no error, however the image does not appear in the email. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you're saving the file to a place on your C Drive, and the path you provide for the HTML email is referencing it with a path in the C drive? You know that not everyone has the same file in the same location on their C drive, right? If you want to display the file, you'll need to provide a proper URL that a client's computer is going to understand.

Comment: If the image is small, use a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***publicPath*** is a ***local folder path***. You will need something like for image -

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/Images/QRCodes/file.png
```

Then, you create image source with ***Absolute URL***.

```
var message = string.Format(
   "<img src='http://www.yourwebsite.com/Images/QRCodes/{0}' width='500' />",  saveFile);
```

*I just guess the folder path. Please make sure it is correct.*

### Other thought

I highly suggest to use `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` instead of hard coded `c:\inetpub\folder`. Mainly, if you move folder location in web server, you do not have recompile the entire application again.

```
string publicPath = string.Format("{0}\\Images\\QRCodes\\{1}", 
    HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, saveFile);
```